# telerik editor Disorganization

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, telerik, styles

I use rad editor in my asp.net page

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager> 
<telerik:RadEditor ID="reSummery" runat="server" > </telerik:RadEditor>
```

there is not no css and js file that referenced to my page but when I run the page editor show me just some point and some linke like "paragraph style , font name , real font size , ...."

you can see from [this link](http://www.mygroups.co/images/aaaa.jpg) my page snapshot

Answer (score 0):

This means that stylesheets are not loaded. You are either missing HTTP handlers in the web.config, or something is blocking them. Check your requests for problems. An option is the CDN so you don't download them from your own server: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager-cdn-support.html.

Make sure you do not have a theme or code-behind setting that toggles the EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet or EnableEmbeddedSkins property to false.

Comment: i add this code to my aspx page <telerik:RadStyleSheetManager 
    ID="RadStyleSheetManager1" 
    runat="server">
    <CdnSettings TelerikCdn="Enabled" />
</telerik:RadStyleSheetManager>   now editor style is ok but any button dont work and i can't write any thing in editor

Comment: i think so that this control is conflict with url routing. when i remove routing code from my global.asax page all the editor works right

Comment: url routing code is  RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("productgroupRout", "{ProductGroupTitle}", "~/ProductGrList.aspx");

Comment: You need to exclude the Telerik handlers from routing. Examine your web.config to see them all. The most important is Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd.
Of course, you can enable the CDN for the RadScriptManager so the Telerik scripts come from the cloud (the same properties as for the stylesheet CDN).
WHen your apps break, look at the network requests - the Telerik controls need a lot of resources and if they can't fetch them, you cannot expect them to work.